# Time and Hinduism

Tags: time, naraka, swarga

It is said that one day of Lord Brahma is so many years in earth and when he goes to sleep earth will get destroyed. *To my knowledge,* There are worlds(we are living in earth) Devas and Gods will live in upper worlds and the lowest worlds are hell, we live in the middle one.

My question is, **time per day seems to be increasing if we move on to the upperworld like in Lord Brahma's case**

1. Heaven is one of the upper worlds and hell is from a lower world. So I have heard may theories, one from([What are levels (types) of Narakas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/what-are-levels-types-of-narakas)) here says the victim has to stay in hell until his time comes. But since hell is a lower world will they experience feeling like they are living forever because one day for us will be many days in hell right(hell is lower world than earth)? So the victim experience longer time? and in heaven will the victims experience shorter time?

Comment: Close: [Why do different Lokas have different velocities of time?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22936/277)

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case indeed. Even if someone has spent a short time in hell it seems to them as if they have been suffering for an eternity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that certainly seems to be the case. As mentioned in the **[Manu Smriti](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu01.htm)**:

> 65. The sun divides days and nights, both human and divine, the night (being intended) for the repose of created beings and the day for exertion.
> 66. **A month is a day and a night of the manes, but the division is according to fortnights.** The dark (fortnight) is their day for active exertion, the bright (fortnight) their night for sleep.
> 67. **A year is a day and a night of the gods;** their division is (as follows): the half year during which the sun progresses to the north will be the day, that during which it goes southwards the night.
> 68. But hear now the brief (description of) the duration of a night and a day of Brahman and of the several ages (of the world, yuga) according to their order.
> 69. They declare that the Krita age (consists of) four thousand years (of the gods); the twilight preceding it consists of as many hundreds, and the twilight following it of the same number.
> 70. In the other three ages with their twilights preceding and following, the thousands and hundreds are diminished by one (in each).
> 71. **These twelve thousand (years) which thus have been just mentioned as the total of four (human) ages, are called one age of the gods.**
> 72. But know that **the sum of one thousand ages of the gods (makes) one day of Brahman, and that his night has the same length.**
> 73. Those (only, who) know that the holy day of Brahman, indeed, ends after (the completion of) one thousand ages (of the gods) and that his night lasts as long, (are really) men acquainted with (the length of) days and nights.

Therefore, what seems to us like years would be just a few days in the Swarga Loka and a few moments in Brahma Loka. So in a manner of speaking, **the time per day or rather the duration pof the day keeps getting longer from lower to higher Lokas.**

Comment: How could a victim experience longer time for his/her sins and lesser time for his good works? why there is no equality?

Comment: Thank you sir for taking your time for research on my question

Comment: My pleasure @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM :) When we enjoy in this material world by giving others pain that pain has to be borne by us all added together so it may appear to be longer. Similarly, the good deeds of most people are few and in between the usual day's work so when they are all combined together they probably wouldn't add to a period bigger than what we get for our bad deeds. This is just my thought about it though not sure if there is any such explanation in the scriptures.

Comment: Love this last thought @Dr.VineetAggarwal